# how to render row query with django_table2

Tags: django, render, django-tables2

hope you will find this message well.

I am new to  django and trying to understand all functionality (its hard for me!). Hope somebody can point me to right direction with small query below?

I've been trying all morning to render 'row' sql query with django_table2 module but I can not  make it work.

```
#view.py
def test(request):
   template = 'test.html'
   
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute('select * from EMC')
      arrays = cursor.fetchall()

   context = {
      'arrays': arrays
   }
   
   return render(request, template, context)


#test.html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}
<h2> Test page</h2> 
<p class="text-justify font-italic"> 

{% render_table arrays %}

</p>
{% endblock %}
```

I presume I am missing to setup table.py but not sure how to form it?
Anybody can point me to right direction?

With above I am getting following error:
Expected table or queryset, not tuple...

Thank you in advance...
ZDZ

Comment: You need to pass a `queryset`, but you are passing a `tuple`.  You can follow their tutorial [here](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html)

Comment: cheers Ejaz. I did follow it and for queryset it works but I cant find a way if I want to use row sql query.... this gives me a problem....